# Show Private Site associates to Community users

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

we have opened the cases for community users means community users can create the cases. Now the problem is Cases have a master detail to custom object site associates and site associates have OWD as private. we can not open the OWD for SA and without that community users wont be able to see the SA and wont be able to provide create the cases without that. Is there any other way to show the private SA to community users? we want to show all the SA to community users. Is it possible with sharing rules??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible via sharing rules and sharing groups. See [Getting Started with Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/) for more on the subject.